# CountDownTimer not initiating in if statement

Tags: java, android

My problem is towards the bottom, I have a boolean, ***ongoing***, which is false. It is supposed to become true with a button press, then initiate a countdown timer, but the timer is not initiated. The timer works placed elsewhere in the code. Sorry if it's a complete mess I'm new to this.

```
public int counter;
public boolean ongoing = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //0-59 number picker to represent seconds
    final NumberPicker secPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.secPicker);
    secPicker.setMaxValue(59);


    Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    Button btnSet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSet);
    Button btnPause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
    final TextView label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCount);


    //sets the time chosen to timer with button press btnSet
    btnSet.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    counter = secPicker.getValue();
                    label.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                }
            }
    );


    //starts timer from selected time, from number picker, with btnStart
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ongoing = true;


        }
    });
    //disables, not worried about this yet
    btnPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ongoing = false;


        }
    });


        //supposed to turn on a timer with button press btnStart, but it does nothing this is my problem.
        if (ongoing == true) {
            //any replacement for 9999999, as an infinite value?
            new CountDownTimer(999999999, 1000) {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    label.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                    counter--;
                    if (counter == -1) {
                        counter = 0;
                        cancel();
                    }
                }

                public void onFinish() {

                }

            }.start();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why u writing like this -  if (ongoing == true)  just simply add if(ongoing), no need to equal to operator

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (ongoing == true) // this will never work for you
```

You have putted above code inside oncreate before you click anything it will get call.

Either you should write below code inside btnStart click event or create one method and call from it.

//supposed to turn on a timer with button press btnStart, but it does nothing this is my problem.

```
if (ongoing == true) {
    //any replacement for 9999999, as an infinite value?
    new CountDownTimer(999999999, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            label.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
            counter--;
            if (counter == -1) {
                counter = 0;
                cancel();
            }
        }

        public void onFinish() {

        }

    }.start();

}
```

Hope these help you.